# Angular - modularly define all services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say I have service modules like so

```
// services/someService.js
export default function($q) {
  return $q.doSomething();
}

// services/anotherService.js
export default function($state) {
  return $state.doAnotherThing();
}
```

And say I have a services index file

```
// services/index.js
import someService from 'someService';
import antoherService from 'anotherService';

export default {
  someService: someService,
  anotherService: anotherService,
}
```

In my angular module, I want to be able to register all of them (eloquently).

```
// awesomeModule.js
import services from './services';

angular.module('awesomeModule', [])
.services(services); // Want to emulate something like this
```

I'm having troubling finding a nice clean way to register the index module so that I can prevent registering each service individually in the `awesomeModule`. Any way to do this?

*** EDIT ***

Using @sdgluck's suggestion I created a utility function/module to register arbitrary service types with a module.

```
// utils.js
export function register(module, type, modules) {
  for (let extension in modules) {
    module[type](extension, modules[extension]);
  }
}
```

Inside of my main module file, I include the utility and register service types like so.

```
// main.js
import {register} from './utils';
register(angular.module('awesomeModule'), 'service', services);
```

Comment: why don't make each service register in-place? if you do the way you want you'll have two modification points every time you need to add a new service.

Comment: I'm using a function to export all modules in a directory from the index file. That won't be an issue as they're auto loaded into index. My example doesn't exactly represent that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot 'batch' register modules in Angular. However using [`forEach`, arrow functions, and destructuring](http://www.2ality.com/2013/02/foreach-es6.html) you can quite cleanly register each of the imports on a single line.

First restructure how you export the services to the following *array of objects* pattern:

```
export default [
    { 
        name: "someService",
        fn: someService
    },
    { 
        name: "anotherService",
        fn: anotherService
    }
]
```

Then use the export like this:

```
// awesomeModule.js
import services from './services';

let app = angular.module('awesomeModule', []);

services.forEach(({name, fn}) => app.service(name, fn));
```

This would yield the same result as if you were to do the following:

```
services.service('someService', services.someService);
services.service('anotherService', services.anotherService);
// and so on...
```

Comment: Ahhh of course! Good suggestion. `services` is an object literal, not an array. We would need `for ... in` in this case... but yes the idea is correct

Comment: Yes, you're quite right! I will update my answer accordingly. Thanks.